# WSDL Client Problem With PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, client

I would like to send the following XML request to a WSDL web service :

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-'.$nonce.'">
<wsse:Username>xxxxx</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxxxx</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-'.$nonce.'" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"> 
<wsu:Created>'.$timestamp.'</wsu:Created>
<wsu:Expires>'.$expiration.'</wsu:Expires> 
</wsu:Timestamp>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<prep:requestListeSeancesCtrlAcces>
     <codeManifestation>xxxx</codeManifestation>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <debutIntervalle/>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <finIntervalle/>
  </prep:requestListeSeancesCtrlAcces>
</soapenv:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

---

How can I do this? I tried PHP soap extension and also NuSOAP with no success :(

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So you're sure this SOAP message fits the WSDL, and you want to know how to send this message as the body of a request to an HTTP endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried HttpRequest::send ? E.g. see the example at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.httprequest-send.php#95734 and fill in your own data:

```
<?php
//set up variables
$theData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-'.$nonce.'">
<wsse:Username>xxxxx</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxxxx</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-'.$nonce.'" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"> 
<wsu:Created>'.$timestamp.'</wsu:Created>
<wsu:Expires>'.$expiration.'</wsu:Expires> 
</wsu:Timestamp>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<prep:requestListeSeancesCtrlAcces>
     <codeManifestation>xxxx</codeManifestation>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <debutIntervalle/>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <finIntervalle/>
  </prep:requestListeSeancesCtrlAcces>
</soapenv:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$options = array();

//create the httprequest object                
$httpRequest_OBJ = new httpRequest($url, HTTP_METH_POST, $options);
//add the content type
$httpRequest_OBJ->setContentType = 'Content-Type: text/xml';
//add the raw post data
$httpRequest_OBJ->setRawPostData ($theData);
//send the http request
$result = $httpRequest_OBJ->send();
//print out the result
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

when i consume wsdl i use cURL

for modifying headers and Envelopes use this:
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soapenvelope);